# Javascript self referential value in object as variable in second value of same object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties, self-reference

For this `object` in javascript:

```
div = 
     {
     id: (changeable value),
     html = 'div id="divName'+id+'"></div>

}
```

This is the most basic form that I can present the problem.
I have a `function` that creates the above `object` and pushes that into an `array`.
Except the above reports :

> 'Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined'

It's not a `variable` but an `object` property, so I'm not confused as to what the error is, but I'm a little unclear on how to reference, as a `variable`, a property within the same `object`.

I have tried added a `method` to the `object` - but that `method` is also `undefined`

```
div = 
     {
     id: (changeable value),
     html = 'div id="divName'+getId()+'"></div>',
     getId()
        {
        return this.id;
    },
}
```

Comment: In addition to the dupe `id` and `div.id` are *different things*. Using `id` in the object literal doesn't refer to the `id` property of the same object - it will always try to reference a variable called `id`. Since there isn't any, it throws an error.

Comment: ...yes. That is my question. I know they are different things.
My question reiterated with variation: 
How do you make the 'id' inside the html property the same as div.id (which does not work)?

Comment: As shown in the dupe. Although I'd wonder if you're going about this the right way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try a method try something like that

```
var div = {
  id: (changeable value),
  html: function(){
    return 'div id = "divName' + this.id + '"></div>'
  }
}
```